# Youtube background on website for mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, wordpress, mobile, youtube

After doing some research, I can’t seem to find a clear answer on this question:

> Is it possible for a website to also show its youtube video background
>   on mobile devices?

I know that by standard, mobile devices don’t autoplay backgrounds. But I’ve also came across a few posts online where people (already tried to contact them) state that there are ways to force a youtube background on mobile devices… one of those posts mentioned jQuery.

Does anyone have the knowledge and solution to do this? Thanks so much in advance!

PS: Using Visual Composer in Wordpress for the background.

PS2: Found this online, but doesn't seem to work on my android:    http://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/GgPLVW

```
visit link to see the code
```

Comment: The answer should be it depends - or even more precise it works in less an less systems / browsers. With iOS 6.1 apple disabled all autoplay logic. On Android latest Chrome, Opera and the Android browser do not support autoplay, FireFox 39 works. On windows phones it seems to be possible. In tribute to bandwidth please don't do it though.

Comment: Thanks for your time and input @alex.michel If you are correct than I guess the best solution is to embed a youtube video player. Have a great day ahead!